# I keep losing a custom bullet style in Word 2011 (on a Mac)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2011

I have set up a custom bullet using a graphic (tried using gif, jpg and png file formats). However, when I quit out of Word and then reopen the document, the custom bullet has lost the graphic. The custom bullet style is listed in the style sheet, but the custom bullet graphic is not retained. This is driving me crazy!!! Can anyone assist?